# ^@ symbol in vim

Tags: vim, file-io

The following symbol shows up when i view my file in vim.

```
---<snip>----
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@fstalone
---<snip>-----
```

The file that I create is by redirecting `stdout` and `stderr` of my utility, like this: `#./my_util > util.log 2>&1`. This file tend to grow quite huge ( ~4 MB )

1. What is this symbol?
2. How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

That is the [null character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character), in a format (which Vim uses a lot, as you've probably noticed) called [caret notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation). Basically, somehow you're getting bytes full of zeros into your file.

Since we don't know what your utility is doing, if it's the culprit, you'll need to show us some code if you want us to help. Otherwise, if you just want to remove the characters from your file, use a substitution:

```
%s/<Ctrl-V><Ctrl-J>//g
```

`Ctrl-V` marks the beginning of an escape sequence. After pressing `Ctrl-J` as well, you should see `^@` appear in your command. Thus, as you guessed, `Ctrl-V, Ctrl-J` is one escape sequence for the null character.

Comment: CTRL-V CTRL-2 will only work with standard QWERTY keyboard. CTRL-V CTRL-J will work with any keyboard layout with a V and a J.

Comment: @Benoit: Oh, nice! I wasn't aware of that. Do you know why this is the case? According to Wikipedia's list of C0 codes, ^J should be the linefeed character `\n`.

Comment: Another way to enter it: `CTRL-K, N, U` as per `:help digraph-table`

Comment: @voithos: ^J is the linefeed character, but Vim stores linefeeds internally as NULLs (presumably as a way of handling Mac/Win/Linux line feed conventions).  There's a bit of description about this in :help NL-used-for-Nul (http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#NL-used-for-Nul)

Comment: @Benoit: Ah, yes, I had forgotten about the digraphs. Note that the `N` and `U` are case-sensitive. I got the Japanese 'nu' character when I used lowercase.

Comment: @DrAl: Very interesting. Which would explain why the null character and the linefeed character are both mapped as `^@`.

Comment: @DrAl: actually the NULL characters are stored as linefeeds (`0x0a`). Not the inverse.

Answer (score 11):

None of the above worked for me. I had a file with '^@' at the end of some lines that I wanted to replace. I managed to substitute it by searching for '[\x0]' using:

```
%s/[\x0]//g
```

I hope it saves someone an hour of their life.
There's an explanation here that I will go back to read when I'm not so busy:
[A discussion with a better explanation](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/search-for-null-td1194026.html)

Comment: That definitely saved me some amount of time. +1. As for an explanation, `\x0` is the hexadecimal representation of the null character. Putting it inside the `[` and `]` just make it easier (less worry about messing it up given different slashes/escapes) by making it a character group. `[\x0]` is the character group containing only the null character. It gets replaced with nothing (deleted). Each null character gets deleted thanks to the `%` and the `/g`.

Answer (score -7):

^@ shows up when you try to open a non text file in vim. For example if you open a exe file or an image file ^@ is shown which is a non-readable character. Try opening the file in some other editor and see the result

Comment: In this case, it's really about searching in a file that can/should be opened in Vim, not a file that shouldn't (like an executable file).