# What does this symbol mean (similiar to ^@) in the context of text editing?

Tags: vim, text, text-editor

Unfortunately, I can't post any pictures due to my lack of reputation but it looks like "^@".

For some context, I have a script that goes through a list of names to generate a configuration file. I run an executable with those configuration and if it doesn't run, the script will proceed to the next name and erase the content of the previous configuration. However, if the executable does run, the script will move on to the next name and append onto the exist configuration. The problem is that when the first iteration is erased, it leaves behind a symbol that would conflict with all subsequent iterations. Any idea what this symbol mean? Much appreciated.

Comment: Read here, see if it helps:http://superuser.com/questions/75130/how-to-remove-this-symbol-with-vim

Comment: `^@` is vim's representation of null characters (U+0000). "[^@ symbol in vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124755/symbol-in-vim)"

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't just look like "^@", it *is* "^@". The `^` denotes a control character; for example `^X` is Control-X. The null character can be entered on most keyboards by typing <kbd>Control-@</kbd>.

Look at a table of ASCII codes. The <kbd>Control</kbd> key, in many cases, modifies a character by subtracting 64 from its ASCII value; thus <kbd>Control-G</kbd> is character (71 - 64) or 7, the ASCII `BEL` character.

As special cases, the ASCII `DEL` character, 127, is represented as "^?", and the `NUL` character can be entered (on most keyboards) by typing <kbd>Control-Space</kbd>. (Vim doesn't use "^ " to represent the NUL character because it would be difficult to read.)

Answer (score 1):

It's how vim displays ASCII nul, i.e. a zero byte.

A simple way to find out the numeric value of a character is to pipe the file through a hex tool such as `xxd` and you will see the `^@` character has value `00`

You can create an empty file then (in input mode) type Ctrl-V Ctrl-Shift-@ to enter the `^@` character, then filter it with `:%!xxd` and you will get:

```
0000000: 000a                                     ..
```

This shows there are two characters with values `00` and `0a` (which is a newline)