# Pyspark dataframe.write.csv use pipe as separator cause strange characters in output file

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe with two columns. Both are of string type.

When I tried to save the dataframe as `csv` with `pipe` as separator with following code:

```
df.write.csv("/outputpath/",sep="|")
```

the output file contains strange characters.

Please see attached screenshot.

[image]

If I instead use tab as separator `sep="\t"`, everything looks good.

Just wonder if anyone has any idea what could go wrong here?

I'm using

Spark 2.2.0 with Python 3.4

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124755/symbol-in-vim

Comment: You have 2 columns? Don't write with `|` character, then... The second column contains that character itself

Comment: Well yes the second column contains the character but unfortunately the reader of the output file is an external program that requires "|" being used as separator

Comment: And that can't be changed? Is it able to handle multiple "columns" missing in the data?